# Parameter error estimate with optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, covariance

Is there a way to estimate the error of the estimated optimization parameters as calculated with scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b (or any of the other bounded optimization routines in the scipy.optimize package)?

Answer (score 8):

L-BFGS-B does not compute the error estimates for you, as you can see [in its documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html).

However, you can estimate the error yourself by computing (numerically or analytically) the hessian of the objective function at the minimum returned by the optimizer: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/DAVIES1/rd_bhatt_cvonline/node9.html

You can compute Hessians numerically in Python for example with [numdifftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Numdifftools).

Comment: @VG_nbi, Welcome to [SO]! If it answers your question satisfactorily , you can mark it as the best answer with the checkmark next to it.